# looking for jQuery date picker with file chooser like behaviour (IE: shift-select for a range, ctrl-select for non contiguous range)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Looking for jQuery date picker with file chooser like behaviour (IE: shift-select for a range, ctrl-select for non contiguous range).  The selected dates can 
then be set in a list. Anyone know of any date pickers/calendars that offer this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/ does ranges (selected by 2 left mouse clicks) and multiple selections (just left click multiple times).

I'm sure it could be adapted to select with accelerator keys <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> if you really need that functionality.

Comment: I've decided to add the functionality to plain old jQuery-Date picker, I found the UI http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/ to be a bit flaky... clicking to select ranges was a little weird (using firefox 4), but thank you.

Comment: Ah ok, I have not tried that datepicker in FF4. Glad you got something working. Is it possible to post your solution? It might be useful for others to see how you implemented it. Or at least a quick description of what you did :-)